# Change the customer's name to a link on an order management page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin, order

Inside the admin control panel, on an order page where I see all the details of the order. I see a list of things: customer name, phone, address, email, etc.
I'm trying to change the client's name to a link with his name.

Anyone have any idea how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Hello @Yotam, you will need to add some details about your request. Are you using a plugin or can you show us some code?

Comment: I use a standard woocommerce plugin. I have no problem changing code. All I want to do is add a link to the name of the client.

Right now: If you click on the name, nothing happens.
What I'm trying to do: If they click on the name, it will move to another page.

Comment: ?????????????????

Comment: Please be kind on this community. We are here to help you. If you are rude, no one will take their time to help you with your issue. Can you tell us on wich Admin page from WooCommerce you want to make the Customer name clickable?

Comment: Thanks. My intention is for a page where the customer's order is edited.

Comment: ??????????????????????????